# i want resume alert Dialog after coming back from another class with Navigator.pop(context)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I want to resumed my alert Dialog after coming back from another activity with Navigator.pop(context),

see the picture when i click on (take picture button) it takes me to camera activity.
when i take picture, how can i resumed alert dialog with old data and picture path

please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) for the dialog widget?